# CKEditor text alignment toolbar buttons

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, wysiwyg

Unable to make text alignment buttons show up on CKEDITOR inline implementation. Tried with v4.1.1 and v4.1.2 on p,div but no luck. Inlineall.html sample file works but as soon as CKEDITOR is loaded in our application(node.js), all works but the alignment buttons.

What could be wrong here? What should I be looking at?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First of all: check whether `CKEDITOR.instances.yourInstance.plugins.justify` is present. This is the first thing you got to know.

If the plugin is loaded in your instance, then I'm sure that the problem is [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter). For some reason, your instance doesn't allow the content required by the justify plugin to run. In such case, the feature is out. You got to configure `config.(extra)allowedContent` for your instance to have it working. If you don't use [config.indentClasses](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-indentClasses), most likely something like this would solve your problem:

```
config.extraAllowedContent = 'p,div{text-align}';
```

Comment: Thank you but did not help. Strange issue

Comment: Still not able to resolve but noticed that if I don't use the inline version, then toolbar buttons appear just fine.

Answer (score 0):

For CKeditor V4 to enable text alignment options in the toolbar add the bellow inside your config.

`config={{extraPlugins: ['justify'],}}`